# Ubuntu 20.04: external mouses/keyboards are not working

Tags: usb, keyboard, xorg, mouse, 20.04

Today I switched from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP envy (laptop). My internal keyboard and touchpad are working fine. But I like to use an external mouse (Logitech M330) and my external keyboard (RAPOO wireless keyboard). In Ubuntu 18.04 these worked fine, but now in Ubuntu 20.04 they don't work. I also tried to use a cabled mouse, which neither worked.

I think I tried already every solution available online. A lot of these solutions included reinstalling *xserver-xorg-input-all*, adding something in the /etc/default/grub, installing *tlp* such that my usb-connected devices were getting enough power, removing some modules and reinstalling them, etc. I also installed Solaar, but this one can also not find my devices.

None of these seem to work and it is frustrating.

The output of *lsusb* is:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05c8:0379 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Truevision HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 24ae:2002 RAPOO RAPOO 5G Wireless Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

so my laptop is recognizing the mouse and the keyboard.

When I try to enable the *hid-logitech-dj* or other Logitech modules, I get following output:

```
$ sudo modprobe hid-logitech-dj 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'hid_logitech_dj': Key was rejected by service
```

When I try the devices on another PC, they work without a configuration. The devices also worked fine during the live boot for the installation of Ubuntu 20.04.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I don't know if this is important, USB flash drives are recognized and I can read/write to/from them.

EDIT:
Unplugging the device and replugging it while looking at `sudo journalctl -f` the output is:

```
Apr 27 08:49:35 michiel-hp kernel: usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Apr 27 08:49:35 michiel-hp kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52f, bcdDevice=30.00
Apr 27 08:49:35 michiel-hp kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Apr 27 08:49:35 michiel-hp kernel: usb 1-1: Product: USB Receiver
Apr 27 08:49:35 michiel-hp kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
Apr 27 08:49:35 michiel-hp mtp-probe[4733]: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Apr 27 08:49:35 michiel-hp mtp-probe[4733]: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Apr 27 08:49:36 michiel-hp mtp-probe[4761]: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Apr 27 08:49:36 michiel-hp mtp-probe[4761]: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
```

Comment: Unplug the device, watch `sudo journalctl -f` as you replug.

Comment: I have added the output of this command when replugging in my Logitech M330. The output was too long to add it here. (see EDIT)

Comment: I ended up installing solaar, not sure if it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by doing the following:

I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04, without any other USB devices connected to my laptop than the USB live boot thumb drive. Now all the external devices work on my laptop, I think this was the easiest solution. I did the reinstall because I still had my backup on my external hard drive and the current installation was new from that day.